# Inverse Distance Weighting with gstat

Tags: r, gstat, spatial-interpolation

I am attempting to execute an idw interpolation with gstat but am unable to.

text =
name,long,lat,waterLevel,elevation,depth

EM_01,18.553392,-34.07027,14.4,20.358,63.0

EM_27,18.574777,-34.068709,16.196,19.966,48.0

EM_29,18.613985,-34.053271,18.766,25.477,39.0

EM_20,18.654089,-34.045177,20.102,36.502,45.0

EM_23,18.643495,-34.037468,22.915,32.715,33.0

EM_13,18.637267,-34.029194,25.516,29.716,33.0

```r
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("gstat")
install.packages("units")
install.packages("terra")

library(sf) 
library(gstat) # geostatistics
library(units) # units of measure
library(terra) 

file = 'text.txt'

#-- import
cfaq <- read.csv(file, header = 1, sep = ',', dec = '.') 

#- set as a spatial feature with xy coords an existing projection
cfaq.sf <- st_as_sf(cfaq, coords=c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) 

#- transform to local crs
cfaq.sf <- st_transform(cfaq.sf, crs = 32734)

#-- construct empty grid
(n.col <- length(seq.e <- seq(min.x <- floor(min(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,2])/1000)*1000,
                              max.x <- ceiling(max(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,2])/1000)*1000, by=1000)))

(n.row <- length(seq.n <- seq(min.y <- floor(min(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,1])/1000)*1000,
                              max.y <- ceiling(max(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,1])/1000)*1000, by=1000)))


#- 2km grid
grid2km <- rast(nrows = n.row, ncols = n.col,
                xmin=min.x, xmax=max.x,
                ymin=min.y, ymax=max.y, crs = st_crs(cfaq.sf)$proj4string,
                resolution = 2000, names="waterLevel")

values(grid2km) <- NA_real_

#-- grid to df
grid2km.df <- as.data.frame(grid2km, xy = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
names(grid2km.df)[1:2] <- c("X", "Y") # match the names of the point dataset

#- idw
grid2km.df$idwp05 = idw(log(waterLevel)  ~ 1, cfaq.sf, 
                        grid2km.df, idp = 0.5)$var1.pred
```

The idw does not succeed.
`Error in .local(formula, locations, ...) :  sf::st_crs(locations) == sf::st_crs(newdata) is not TRUE`

How can this be? The `crs` is defined.
How do I execute the idw successfully please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is not wrong; though note that it does not complain about CRS of `cfaq.sf` (`locations` param). You are using `grid2km.df` for `newdata` parameter, and that's the one with no CRS. Besides, `newdata` should should be `Spatial`, `sf` or `stars`, so perhaps try to use `stars` for grid:

```r
library(sf) 
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(gstat) 
library(stars)

text_ <- "name,long,lat,waterLevel,elevation,depth
          EM_01,18.553392,-34.07027,14.4,20.358,63.0
          EM_27,18.574777,-34.068709,16.196,19.966,48.0
          EM_29,18.613985,-34.053271,18.766,25.477,39.0
          EM_20,18.654089,-34.045177,20.102,36.502,45.0
          EM_23,18.643495,-34.037468,22.915,32.715,33.0
          EM_13,18.637267,-34.029194,25.516,29.716,33.0"

# -- import
cfaq <- read.csv(text = text_, header = 1, sep = ',', dec = '.') 

# - set as a spatial feature with xy coords an existing projection
cfaq.sf <- st_as_sf(cfaq, coords=c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) 

# - transform to local crs
cfaq.sf <- st_transform(cfaq.sf, crs = 32734)

cfaq.bb <- st_bbox(cfaq.sf)
cfaq.bb[c("xmin","ymin")] <-   floor(cfaq.bb[c("xmin","ymin")]/1000)*1000
cfaq.bb[c("xmax","ymax")] <- ceiling(cfaq.bb[c("xmax","ymax")]/1000)*1000

grid2km <- st_as_stars(cfaq.bb, dx = 2000)
grid2km
#> stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s):
#>         Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
#> values     0       0      0    0       0    0
#> dimension(s):
#>   from to  offset delta                refsys x/y
#> x    1  5  274000  2000 WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S [x]
#> y    1  3 6233000 -2000 WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S [y]

i <- idw(log(waterLevel) ~ 1, cfaq.sf, grid2km, idp = 0.5)
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]
as.data.frame(i)
#>         x       y var1.pred var1.var
#> 1  275000 6232000  2.941439       NA
#> 2  277000 6232000  2.957383       NA
#> 3  279000 6232000  2.982699       NA
#> 4  281000 6232000  3.031934       NA
#> 5  283000 6232000  3.036951       NA
#> 6  275000 6230000  2.918279       NA
#> 7  277000 6230000  2.938086       NA
#> 8  279000 6230000  2.963870       NA
#> 9  281000 6230000  2.995139       NA
#> 10 283000 6230000  3.010777       NA
#> 11 275000 6228000  2.875184       NA
#> 12 277000 6228000  2.907489       NA
#> 13 279000 6228000  2.948413       NA
#> 14 281000 6228000  2.972109       NA
#> 15 283000 6228000  2.986109       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @margusl. I would appreciate the ability to interpolate into the df ---like the code originally wants: grid2km$idw05, etc.--- how can I assign a `crs` to the `df` please. I am failing too with `grid2km.df <- st_set_crs(grid.df, st_crs(32734))`

Comment: Maybe a not the best choice of words from me, but you can't . Error you included in your question states that in your current settings, `grid2km.df` is evaluated as `newdata`  argument, but that can't be a data.frame, it must be either `Spatial`, `sf` or `stars`. You can check `?gstat::idw` for reference.